# How should I connect two sites through the internet?

Tags: routing, vpn, network-access

I have two sites which are 3km away from each other, both sites have internet access from the same ISP. I would like both sites to have access to each other throught the internet routers (TP-Link TD-W8968). Is it possible?? if not, please explain what do I need to achieve the connection with the lowest cost possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 4):

You need to investigate site-to-site VPN

https://www.tp-link.com/ae/faq-244.html